# Trouble finding unique values

Tags: r, unique

I have a problem with unique command. When I run unique for each variable I have no problems , but when I try to run for more than one variable I get trouble.

This is my database:

```
structure(list(M1 = c("AMZN PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", 
"ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity"), M2 = c("AMZN PE Equity", 
"ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity")), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Both variables( M1, M2)  have the same characters but are repeated in different proportions( ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity is repeated  six times in M1 , but is repeated seven times in M2).

This is my code for more than one variable:

```
morethan1<- unique(testrep[c("M1", "M2")])
```

and this is my output:

```
      M1                       M2
1      AMZN PE Equity        AMZN PE Equity
2        ANDAHUC1 PE        ANDAHUC1 PE
7         ANDAHUC1 PE       ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity
8 ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity       ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity
```

As you can see there are some repeated names yet.

This is my code for just one variable:

```
just1 <- unique(testrep[c("M1")])
```

I have no problem in this case:

```
         M1
1      AMZN PE Equity
2         ANDAHUC1 PE
8 ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity
```

Also I have the numbers (1 , 2 , 8), I want numbers to appear in order(1 ,2 3)

Finally, If I have 100 columns( M1 to M100) how can I modify my first code(M1:M00)?

Another way:

```
bothvariables <- subset(unique(testrep), M1 != M2)
```

This is my output:

```
         M1                           M2
7 ANDAHUC1 PE               ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity
```

But I want this output:

```
         M1                            M2
      AMZN PE Equity             AMZN PE Equity
         ANDAHUC1 PE             ANDAHUC1 PE
 ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity             ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity
```

No matter if the names are repeated different number of times in M1, M2 I want an output that show me the unique names inside M1 and M2 columns.

Now I try with a one more column : M3

This is my new database:

```
structure(list(M1 = c("AMZN PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", 
"ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity"), M2 = c("AMZN PE Equity", 
"ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity"), M3 = c("AMZN PE Equity", "AMZN PE Equity", 
"AMZN PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", "ANDAHUC1 PE", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", "ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity", 
"ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity")), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code:

```
testrep %>%
    distinct(M1, .keep_all = TRUE)

This is the output:

                   M1                  M2                  M3
1      AMZN PE Equity      AMZN PE Equity      AMZN PE Equity
2         ANDAHUC1 PE         ANDAHUC1 PE      AMZN PE Equity
3 ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity
```

I have the same problem now, just because I added a new column.

this is my expected output:

```
               M1                M2                  M3
1      AMZN PE Equity      AMZN PE Equity      AMZN PE Equity
2         ANDAHUC1 PE         ANDAHUC1 PE      ANDAHUC1 PE  
3 ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity   ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity    ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity
```

Comment: There are repeated *names*, yes, but not repeated *pairs* of names.

Comment: @r2evans I have same number of columns and rows, names are repeated different times in each variable, that's the problem. Is there a way to get an output like the last code but for both variables(M1 and M2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
 testrep[paste0("M", 1:100)]
```

Or with `startsWith`

```
testrep[startsWith(names(testrep), "M")]
```

Or using `grep`

```
testrep[grep("^M\\d+$", names(testrep))]
```

---

Regarding the row number issue, it can be set to `NULL` to get the default numbering

```
row.names(just1) <- NULL
```

---

We can use `distinct` with `.keep_all`

```
library(dplyr)
testrep %>%
    distinct(M1, .keep_all = TRUE)
#                   M1                  M2
#1      AMZN PE Equity      AMZN PE Equity
#2         ANDAHUC1 PE         ANDAHUC1 PE
#3 ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity
```

We could get the `unique` from. each column separately and then `unnest` it

```
library(tidyr)
testrep2 %>%
     summarise_all(list(~ list(unique(.)))) %>%
     unnest(everything())
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  M1                  M2                  M3                 
#  <chr>               <chr>               <chr>              
#1 AMZN PE Equity      AMZN PE Equity      AMZN PE Equity     
#2 ANDAHUC1 PE         ANDAHUC1 PE         ANDAHUC1 PE        
#3 ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity ALICPRLl1 Pe Equity
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have the same problem for unique: there are some repeated names yet.

Comment: @JoseMontoya `unique` for multiple columns check whether the combination for a row is unique across columns.  Not clear what you wanted.  If you need to do this only a particular column, that can be done

Comment: I want an output like my last code but for more than one variable. As you can see  when I try to use unique for more than one variable I get some repeated names that I don't want.

Comment: @JoseMontoya when yoou have more than one variables, it would look for unique rows based on that number of columns.  Is it based on a single variable?

Comment: I want this: Imagine I have 10 times the name "Frank" and 8 times the name "Anna" in M1. On the other hand, I have 7 times the name "Frank" and 11 times the name "Anna" in M2. So i have the same number of rows but the names are repeated in different ways in each variable( M1 and M2). So i want an output that show me  the unique names. For example, in M1 : Frank, Anna , in M2: Frank , Anna. No matter if the names are repeated different number of times in M1, M2.

Comment: @JoseMontoya Do you need `subset(unique(df1), M1 != M2)` assuming the example is `df1 <- data.frame(M1 = rep(c("Frank", "Anna"), c(10, 8)), M2 = rep(c("Frank", "Anna"), c(7, 11)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Yeah that is an example but what I really have is  multiple names and are repeated different times in each variables( M1, M2). How can I modify that code?

Comment: @JoseMontoya can you pleasee update your example with expected output so that it becomes more clear to me

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: I have the same problem when I add another column: M3. I've just edited my post.

Comment: @JoseMontoya it. will be grouped by 'M1' alone or 'M1 and 'M2'

Comment: @JoseMontoya what would be the expected output for the edit

Comment: @JoseMontoya your expected output shows that it is not following the row order positions.  Can you check my updated answer

Comment: I get this error message:  
Error: Column `M1` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 3

Comment: @JoseMontoya if it is a warning message, it is fine

Comment: @JoseMontoya try `testrep2 %>%
     summarise_all(list(~ list(unique(.)))) %>%
     unnest(everything())` i think the version difference matters

Comment: Perfect!  it worked for all the columns , that's what I wanted. Thank you! :)